# gopls neovim lsp server json rpc parse error on PCompletionListPCompletion.capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionList.itemDefaults

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

After configuring neovim with mason, mason-lspconfig, nvim-lspconfig, null-ls, and mason-null-ls and installing the gopls lsp server, I recently started getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQfkN.png) upon opening a go file.

In plain text:

```
RPC[Error] code_name = ParseError, message = "JSON RPC parse error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field PCompletionListPCompletion.capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionList.itemDefaults of type []string"
```

When I run `:LspInfo` I see that `null-ls` is attached to the current buffer and that `gopls` is recognized as being "available," but `gopls` won't attach to the buffer (filetypes, root directory and cmd all look correct).

My configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/KobraKommander9/dot-files/blob/main/nvim/.config/nvim/lua/kobra/lsp/init.lua).

After searching, I have found many supposed fixes for gopls ~v0.6 in relation to json parse errors, but they do not seem applicable.

My gopls version is v0.10.1 and `goplz api-json` seems to print correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured this out. Had to run `:checkhealth` and found several warnings. After fixing all the warnings, removing duplicated go installations on my machine, upgrading to go 1.19 and reinstalling gopls, got it working again.